# PHP syntax: Zend Framework view script dilemma

Tags: php, zend-view

So I want to use a jQuery tab container in my view script. I have tested it so I know I already have everything working.

```
<?php $this->tabContainer()->addPane('container-name', 'label', 'content goes here'); ?>
<?php echo $this->tabContainer('container-name'); ?>
```

But this is the content that I want to put into the pane:

```
<?php if (count($this->resources->links) > 0): ?>
    <h3>Links</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->resources->links as $link): ?>
        <li><?php echo $link->title; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I get that if/foreach block into the content param of the addPane function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you want is `ob_start()`, `ob_get_clean()` pair.

```
<?php
ob_start();
if (count($this->resources->links) > 0): ?>
    <h3>Links</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->resources->links as $link): ?>
        <li><?php echo $link->title; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;
$things = ob_get_clean();
$this->tabContainer()->addPane('container-name', 'label', $things);
echo $this->tabContainer('container-name'); ?>
```